# When creating my own custom yeoman generator, how do I use a variable from the prompt in my Gruntfile?

Tags: javascript, templating, yeoman-generator

When building a yeoman generator. Given, my index.js contains:

```
...
prompting: function () {
    var done = this.async();

    // have Yeoman greet the user
    this.log(this.yeoman);

    var questions = [
        {
            name: 'value',
            message: 'Give me some value?'
        },
    ];

    this.prompt(questions, function (answers) {
        this.value = answers.value;
        done();
    }.bind(this));
},
...

writing: function () {
    this.copy("_Gruntfile.js", "Gruntfile.js");
}
...
```

and my answer to the prompt 'Give me some value?' is "test". How do I use the value from the prompt in the `_Gruntfile` to generate:

```
 uglify: {
       dist: {
         files: {
           '<%= yeoman.dist %>/test.min.js': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/test.js']
         }
       }
    },
```

I've tried:

```
uglify: {
       dist: {
         files: {
           '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%% value%>.min.js': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%value%>.js']
         }
       }
    },
```

and

```
uglify: {
       dist: {
         files: {
           '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= value%>.min.js': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= value%>.js']
         }
       }
    },
```

to get the generator to replace `<%% value%>` or `<%= value%>` with "test" but nothing happens when it's run. The second option works when used in my _bower.json. e.g `"name": "<%= value%>"` becomes `"name": "test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`this.copy()`](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/actions.html#copy) just copies the file, you should instead use [`this.template()`](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/actions.html#template) to parse it:

```
this.template("_Gruntfile.js", "Gruntfile.js");
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve my problem. I did some more digging though and both copy and template actions run it through the templating engine, but the way in which they do it are different. That's how my bower.json got processed. You can also run `this.template("_Gruntfile.js","Grunfile.js")` it's a question of source and destination names

Comment: So does my solution by itself solves your problem or did you have to do something extra?

Comment: It solves my problem, just thought I would add some extra information so that you can maybe improve the answer. My understanding is that one of the goals of stackoverflow is to build a knowledge base.

Comment: Certainly, I’ll update the it once I get on the computer, I just wasn’t sure whether it fixed the problem or was just a part of the solution.

Comment: Edited. You said that `this.copy()` also runs it through the templating engine, could you find any references to back that up?

Comment: No, but if you look in the code [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/actions/actions.js) you'll see that `action.copy` and `action.template` execute `action.engine`

Comment: You’re right. Though I still don’t understand how it works, so I can’t improve my answer further, for now.